# PKI: web server certificate

Tags: iis, certificate, pki

I'm learning the process of authentication in PKi environement.

Imagine I have two web servers (example IIS) that are configured with same TLS certificate to bind websites.

Now, if I remove and add a new certificate on one of two servers. It's still have the same common name but generated with a different private key.

I wonder if having two certificate with the same common name (subject) with two different private keys will be a problem?

What information is used by the client to choose a specific public key to encrypt information?

I hope that my question is clear. Let me know if you need more information.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use the different private key certificates for the same common name. If your website is set up on multiple servers (behind a load balancer, application request router), this can help segment access and improve your security controls. may i know how you are going to set the site binding? and private key will be used for the encryption.

Answer (score 0):

No matter how many certificates you installed to Windows certificate stores, IIS only uses the mappings in Windows HTTP API to determine the actual server certificate to use for a specific site,

https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background

If you are familiar with SSL/TLS handshake process, you can easily see in that way the browser always knows which public key to use.

Answer (score 0):

Will it be a problem? The answer is *maybe*.

Assuming a modern browser, then the PKI works broadly like this:

- the browser first uses DNS to resolve the FQDN into an address;
- then the browser sends a TLS client hello to it, which contains an
  [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) matching the FQDN;
- the server receives the TLS client hello, checks whether the FQDN matches ones it owns, then responds with a TLS server hello containing the X.509 certificate;
- the browser receives the TLS server hello, then checks that the certificate is valid;
- that the [SubjectAltName](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2818#section-3.1) (SAN) field contains the FQDN (SAN has replaced
  CN); and
- that the certificate is signed by a [CA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) that it trusts.

At this point the browser doesn't actually care whether you have multiple servers with multiple different certificates (which can be normal during a patch where they are being revoked and replaced).

The *maybe* comes afterwards, because there are a collection of HTTP extensions that can cause the browser to reject the certificate if it does not comply with what it is expecting, such as [Expect-CT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9163) and [HSTS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797).